# how to create a XML::Linq XElement in C++, not C#

Tags: c++, .net, xml, linq

Ok, I've been using C# for a while , and creating a new xElement in C# is simple

```
XElement NewElement = new XElement(NodeName, new XAttribute("Setting", Nodevalue));
```

where NodeName and Nodevalue are strings.  Simple.

but we're trying to squeeze every microsecond out in some speed test so we're converting the project to C++ (not my forte)

what I have is this

`XElement^ XMLHelper::QElement(String^ NodeName, String^ Nodevalue)
        {
            char NodeSetting[8] = "Setting";

            XAttribute^ NewAttribute = gcnew XAttribute(gcnew XName(),Nodevalue));
            XElement^ Built = gcnew XElement(NodeName, NewAttribute);
            return Built;
        }`

But I can't see how to get the XAttribute name set to "Setting"

Microsoft's Documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute(v=vs.100).aspx
 references the constructor but their examples for C++ all return 
"No code example is currently available or this language may not be supported."

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not using the standard C++, you're using the managed C++([C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx)). The difference is: the standard C++ only deal with native memory; while C++/CLI is built on CLR(Common language runtime), it can access both native and managed memory.

So for your code:

```
char NodeSetting[8] = "Setting";
```

This line defines a variable which is native, not a managed one. While for the name of XAttribute, it required a manage one(a reference object), so you should use this:

```
 String^ NodeSetting = gcnew String("Setting");
```

Comment: I ended up using this line of code:
XElement^ Built = gcnew XElement(NodeName, gcnew XAttribute(gcnew String("Setting"),Nodevalue));

Still wish there were more C++ samples of XML::Linq on the web though.

Answer (score 0):

Got it after all.
You can't use gcnew XName() as you can't assign the name
you can't also just use XAttribute("STRING",Value);

But you CAN use XAttribute(gcnew String("STRING"),Value);